# Imperative replacement of recursion with recursion syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, decorator, python-decorators

althought I know, that the heading is strange, I dont know how to better describe the problem. Lets say, that I have tree, where I compute attributes recursively. Simple example:

```
class Child:
    @property
    def attribute(self):
        return 1
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.left = Child()
        self.right = Child()
    @property
    def attribute(self):
        return self.left.attribute + self.right.attribute


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = Parent()
    print(tree.attribute)
```

And I want to replace the recursion with imperative style. Thats not the problem, I made this program:

```
from inspect import signature
class Child:
    def attribute(self, context):
        context.execute(lambda: 3)
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.left = Child()
        self.right = Child()
    def attribute(self, context):
        context.execute(lambda l, r:
                        l + r
                        )
        context.evaluate(self.left, Child.attribute.__name__)
        context.evaluate(self.right, Child.attribute.__name__)

class Context:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__evaluation_stack = []
        self.__value_stack = []
    def evaluate(self, tree, attribute):
        self.__evaluation_stack.append(('attr', tree, attribute))
    def compute(self):
        while self.__evaluation_stack:
            cur = self.__evaluation_stack.pop()
            if cur[0] == 'attr':
                getattr(cur[1], cur[2])(self)
            if cur[0] == 'lambda':
                count_of_parameters = len(signature(cur[1]).parameters)
                params = []
                if count_of_parameters > 0:
                    params = self.__value_stack[-count_of_parameters:]
                    del self.__value_stack[-count_of_parameters:]
                val = cur[1](*params)
                self.__value_stack.append(val)
        return self.__value_stack.pop()   
    def execute(self, what):
        self.__evaluation_stack.append(('lambda', what))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = Context()
    tree = Parent()
    context.evaluate(tree, Parent.attribute.__name__)
    result = context.compute()
    print(result)
```

The usage of tuples is just illustration. I will replace it later with polymorphism or something. Also the context methods will have nicer names and probably chaining, so the code will not looks so awful.

Now, why i need your help. As you see, the body is changed (nodes must call specific methods on Context and evaluation is lambda). Is there a native way (meaning in the sense of decorators or whatever Python can provide) to use the recursion (or very simmilar) syntax, that will use context under the hood?

The main problem is, that methods needs to stop in the middle of execution and wait for results. The results must be provided back and execution must continue. For example I know that iterators in JavaScript can break the execution and you can also pass value (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Advanced_generators). Something similar in Python?

Live example: https://repl.it/@PatrikValkovic/ImperativeRecursion-EventDriven

---

**EDIT1 - generators**

I tried using generators, which looks much better. Code is bellow, as so as link to live version. Good thing is, that Context does not use reflexion and hold just one value, instead of stack. Maybe someone can come with even more recursion-like version?

Link: https://repl.it/@PatrikValkovic/ImperativeRecursion-Generators

```
class Child:
    def attribute(self):
        return 3
        yield
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.left = Child()
        self.right = Child()
    def attribute(self):
        left_value = yield self.left.attribute
        right_value = yield self.right.attribute
        return left_value + right_value

class Context:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__evaluation_stack = []
        self.__value = None
    def evaluate(self, attr):
        self.__evaluation_stack.append(attr())
        while self.__evaluation_stack:
            try:
                working = self.__evaluation_stack.pop()
                resp = working.send(self.__value) if self.__value else next(working)
                self.__value = None
                self.__evaluation_stack.append(working)
                self.__evaluation_stack.append(resp())
            except StopIteration as e:
                self.__value = e.value
        return self.__value


context = Context()
tree = Parent()
result = context.evaluate(tree.attribute)
print(result)
```

Comment: Are you looking for Coroutines? https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: AFAIK Javascript copied `yield` from python (and I believe python took it from C#).